# field does not allow filtering (no relation used)

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a problem with django and tastypie

Given is the following code:

```
class CandidatePollResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Candidate.objects.all()
        resource_name = "candidate-poll"
        filtering = {"status": ALL }

class Candidate(Profile):
    """
    This profile stores all information about a candidate.
    """
    status = models.CharField(_('status'), max_length=15, blank=True, choices=CANDIDATE_STATUS_CHOICES)

class Profile(models.Model):
    """
    Abstract basic class all profiles should inherit.
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,related_name='%(class)s',)
    invitationdate = models.DateField(_('invitationdate'), null=True, blank=True)
    confirmationdate = models.DateField(_('confirmationdate'), null=True, blank=True)
    activation_key = models.CharField(_('activation_key'), max_length=32, blank=True)
    # Adding of "class" here is important for this to work. See
    # http://thedjangoforum.com/board/thread/417/reverse-query-name-for-field-clash/?page=1
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name='%(class)s_created', blank=True, null=True)

    objects = ProfileManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Each time we try to do a call to filter the result set ( `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/candidate-poll/?status__exact=new` ), I always get the following error

`The 'status' field does not allow filtering.`

How can I enable filtering on that field?

Answer (score 4):

I think that your syntax is not exactly correct.
Instead of:

```
filtering = {"status": ("exact", "in",), }
```

try:

```
filtering = {"status": [ "exact", "in" ] }
```

if that doesn't work, you could try:

```
filtering = {"status": ALL }
```

and proceed from there. `ALL` should allow everything so if it didn't work this would mean the problem lies elsewhere.

For more information please take a look at [Tastypie docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#basic-filtering)

Comment: Allowing "ALL" filtering helped at all :( Any idea where I could start searching for that error?

Comment: It all looks quite good, perhaps try simplifying your field definition, i.e. instead of `status = models.CharField(_('status'), max_length=15, blank=True, choices=CANDIDATE_STATUS_CHOICES)` try `status = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)` and see if that works. If you can, please also provide source for `Profile` model as it may play a role too.

Comment: it didnt work. slowly im getting desperate. I added the profile class to my question. thanks for your patience and support!

Comment: You're welcome :) Perhaps you should try temporarily replacing your current `Candidate` model with something super simple, i.e. instead of inheritance and custom manager, define a simple model from scratch with just one `status = CharField(...)` and see if Tastypie will allow you to filter that.

Comment: well, in the end it was a formatting/indentation error, which came out as soon as our fourth developer opned it in her editor. so it is more a stupid me error

Answer (score 0):

go with

filtering = { 'status' : ['exact'] }

now you can use in URL http://localhost:3000/api/v1/candidate-poll/?status=new and the field gets filtered with only json data having status as new